# $\mathbb Q$ Field extension

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Consider the Field $F = \mathbb Q(2^{\frac 1 3})$, Is $\sqrt 2 \in F$?

I'm trying to figure out how to determine that and similar questions, can you give me a hint or some guidance on how to do that?

Comment: You can use degrees. $\lvert F : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \rvert = 3$, while $\lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q} \rvert = 2$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti faster than I could type the tex xD

Comment: @AndreasCaranti How can I use degrees?

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? If you don't show any work, it is near impossible for people to give an answer at an appropriate level.

Comment: @Magdiragdag on my answer he said that he attempted using how a vector space is formed with $\mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓})$ then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},2^{⅓}) : \mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓})] = 1 \implies [\mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓},\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$

**Hint 2:** (A different approach)

The basis of the vector space $\mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is
$$
1,2^{⅓},2^{⅔}
$$

Comment: I dont see how those hints help me to prove/disprove it.

Comment: Since we have that $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓},\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 3$ then it should follow that
$$
3 = [\mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓},\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓},\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q} ]
$$
but what do we know about the degree of these extensions?

Comment: @Snufsan as for the second hint, since that is the basis, you can form any element in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{⅓})$ with a linear combination of them. Namely you should be able to find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $a + b 2^{⅓} + c 2^{⅔} = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I tried to use the second hint before asking the question, but I didnt know how to determine if there is or not such linear combination.

For the first hint, You used the fact that the extension over $\sqrt 2 , 2^{\frac1 3}$ is acctualy a series of simple extensions, but why does the equality follows? is it always true that a series of extensions degree is the multiplextion of the degrees of each extension?

Comment: @Snufsan Yes, if $F \subset B \subset E$ are fields with $[E:B], [B : F]$ finite then $[E : F] = [E : B][B : F]$. This is called the degree formula in my reference (Galois Theory by Rotman). More can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension).

Comment: Also note that $(a+2^{⅓}b + 2^{⅔}c)^2 = a^2 + 2^{⅓}ab + 2^{⅔}ac + 2^{⅓}ab + 2^{⅔}b^2 + \cdots$ and you'll find some restrictions on $a,b,c$ that cause the such $a,b,c$ not to exist.